# X11: Some applications misunderstand xkb keymap

Tags: xkb, keyboard-event

I want to remap my keys in the following way: `ctrl+j/k` -> `left/right` and `ctrl+h/l` -> `ctrl+left/right`. So I got the default `xkb` file and added the following contents into it.

First, I defined a new type:

```
type "newType" {
    modifiers= Shift+Control+Lock;
    map[Shift]= Level2;
    map[Lock]= Level2;
    map[Control]= Level3;
    map[Control+Lock]= Level3;
    level_name[Level1]= "Base";
    level_name[Level2]= "Shift";
    level_name[Level3]= "Control";
};
```

Then I redefined the `keysym` of `h/j/k/l`:

```
    key <AC06> {
    type= "SimonCtrlMap",
    symbols[Group1]= [               h,               H,            Left ],
    actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<LEFT>) ]
};
key <AC07> {
    type= "SimonCtrlMap",
    symbols[Group1]= [               j,               J,            Left ],
    actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<LEFT>, clearmods=Control) ]
};
key <AC08> {
    type= "SimonCtrlMap",
    symbols[Group1]= [               k,               K,            Right ],
    actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<RGHT>, clearmods=Control) ]
};
key <AC09> {
    type= "SimonCtrlMap",
    symbols[Group1]= [               l,               L,            Right ],
    actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<RGHT>) ]
};
```

And then I loaded the new `xkb` file with `xkbcomp`, the key map works in most of my applications, such as `firefox`, `gnome-terminal`, `gedit`. However, in some applications, the key map does not work.

For example, in `vnc-viewer`, if I press `ctrl+j/k`, it will be recognized as `ctrl+left/right`, instead of `left/right`.

The most puzzling phenomena is in `nautilus`, the default file explorer for `gnome`, if I press `l`, it will be recognized as `ctrl+l`!

Can anyone give me a suggestion to fix it? I have seen `multi-group` method and `overlay` method mentioned at the link https://superuser.com/questions/801611/how-to-make-all-applications-respect-my-modified-xkb-layout?newreg=4416b0444d2949079d57d2848f86452a. I do not want to use `multi-group` method, because `ctrl` plays some other roles besides my key map. And the `overlay` method just does not solve my problem.